# iPhone - Why didn't the Static Analyzer pick this up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, static-analysis

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* playerList;
```

...

```
team.playerList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.playerList];
```

This is a memory leak right?

So why couldn't the static analysier pick this up?

Comment: Naturally you've used @synthesize elsewhere, rather than writing your own getter and setter?

Comment: Cool, just thought it was worth asking to finish the thought. I was able to replicate the behaviour you report. At a guess, I'd imagine the analyser isn't smart enough to spot that you don't subsequently release the object twice sometime during program flow and doesn't recognise the convention. But that's just a guess and not substantial enough to be an actual answer since it's pretty much just "this is something the analyser gets wrong", more or less repeating the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a memory leak; you need to either autorelease that array or manually release it after setting the property. I'm not sure why the static analyzer missed it—you might consider [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) against the developer tools.